# MySQL DELETE from two tables does not delete all records

Tags: mysql, join, innodb, cascade

innodb_version: 10.3.34

version: 10.3.34-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Simple query:

```
DELETE `anode`, `adevice`
FROM `adevice`
JOIN `adevice_node`
    ON `adevice_node`.`device` = `adevice`.`id`
JOIN `anode`
    ON `anode`.`id` = `adevice_node`.`node`
WHERE `adevice`.`id` = 1
```

Structure:
(adevice <- adevice_node -> anode)

```
CREATE TABLE `adevice` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `adevice` VALUE (1);

CREATE TABLE `anode` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `anode` VALUES (1), (2);

CREATE TABLE `adevice_node` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `node` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_adevice_node_1_idx` (`device`),
  KEY `fk_adevice_node_2_idx` (`node`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_adevice_node_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device`) REFERENCES `adevice` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_adevice_node_2` FOREIGN KEY (`node`) REFERENCES `anode` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `adevice_node` VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2);
```

I suppose, it must delete all rows from `adevice` with `id` = 1, all children from `adevice_node` (CASCADE) and all their children from `anode`, but it does not: only one row from `anode` deleted (and all needed rows from another tables).
Why? What is the right way to do this deletion IN ONE QUERY?

P.S: If we complicate the query (add several JOINs after `adevice_node` and third table in deletion list), then all the necessary records are deleted...

Update: It might be this old bug...
[bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44207](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44207)

Comment: Hi, can you show us your table structures and expected output?

Comment: your table with data in it. and kindly check this demo I made in sql fiddle. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f8af11b2e5846dd0effca7af2c8afcb4

Comment: Fonz, your demo is correct. As you can see, there is one row left in `anode` with `id`=2

Comment: I just used your query as you can see in the demo I made.

Comment: I see that you made the demo. What is your point..?

Comment: When you delete device number 1, do you really want all the nodes associated with it?  Those nodes might be associated with other devices.

Comment: Rick James, yes I definitely want them to be deleted. First, I guarantee that these nodes will not be associated with any other devices. Secondly, the conversation is not even about this: regardless of the previous fact, MySQL works strangely.

The conversation is not about the implementation at the architecture level, but about the behavior of the DELETE operation in MySQL. The structure described above is just an antics of a much more massive structure in order to show the very essence of the bug.